# Hive aggregate columns based on different conditions

Tags: select, hive

Assume my table looks like this:

```
cust_id, domain, year, mon, day
1, google.au, 2018, 10, 1
2, virgin.com.au, 2018, 10, 1
3, hotmail.au, 2018, 10, 1
4, yahoo.au, 2018, 10, 1
1, foobar.au, 2018, 10, 1
3, foobar.com.au, 2018, 10, 1
15, haha.com, 2018, 10, 1
11, hehe.net, 2018, 10, 1
```

I need to group by year/mon/day and aggregate columns based on different conditions:

```
1) count of distinct domains ending with .au but not .com.au
2) count of distinct domains ending with .com.au
3) count of distinct hostnames where cust_id in a specific list, let's assume (1, 2, 3, 4)
4) count of all distinct hostnames
```

So my output would look like:

```
2018, 10, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8
```

I'm leaning towards using subqueries for each condition and then joining them:

```
select condition_1.year, condition_1.mon, condition_1.day, condition_1.c1, condition_3.c3, condition_4.c4
    from
(select year, mon, day, count(distinct domain) c1 from mytable where year = 2018 and mon = 10 and day = 1
and domain rlike '[.]au' and domain not rlike '[.]com[.]au'
group by year, mon, day) condition_1

full outer join

(select count(distinct domain) c2 from mytable where year = 2018 and mon = 10 and day = 1
and domain rlike '[.]com[.]au') condition_2

full outer join

(select count(distinct domain) c3 from mytable where year = 2018 and mon = 10 and day = 1
and cust_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)) condition_3

full outer join
(select count(distinct hostname) c4 from mytable where year = 2018 and mon = 10 and day = 1) condition_4
```

This seems horribly inefficient, though I can't  think of a better way. 
The CASE statement would not work here as I need distinct counts.
How could I achieve this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with regular expressions and with conditional aggregation.

```
select year,mon,day
,count(distinct case when domain regexp '(?<!\.com)\.au$' then domain end) as ends_with_au
,count(distinct case when domain regexp '\.com\.au$' then domain end) as ends_with_com_au
,count(distinct case when cust_id in (1,2,3,4) then domain end) as specific_cust
,count(distinct domain) as all_domains
from mytable
group by year,mon,day
```

The regexp `(?<!\.com)\.au$` uses a negative lookbehind assertion to check for the preceding characters to `.au` are not `.com`. `$` metacharacter means match `.au` as the last 3 characters in the string. `.` has to be escaped with `\`.

Comment: it can be extended as you mentioned. unless i see the `then` condition in your comment, i can't really tell.

Comment: I'm using `count(distinct case when domain regexp '\.us$' or domain regexp '\.gb$' or domain regexp '\.fr$' domain regexp '\.fi$' then domain end)`

Comment: it should work as expected..note you can simplify it to `domain regexp '\.us$|\.gb$|\.fr$|\.fi$'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `collect_set()` - it collects distinct set, ignoring NULLs, use `size` function to get the number of elements (already distinct):

```
select
      year, mon, day,
      size(condition_1) as condition_1_cnt,
      size(condition_2) as condition_2_cnt,
      size(condition_3) as condition_3_cnt,
      size(condition_4) as condition_4_cnt    
 from
   (
    select year, mon, day,
       collect_set(case when domain rlike '(?<![.]com)[.]au' then domain end) condition_1,
       collect_set(case when domain rlike '[.]com[.]au'      then domain end) condition_2,
       collect_set(case when cust_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)         then domain end) condition_3,
       collect_set(hostname)                                                  condition_4
      from mytable 
     where year = 2018 and mon = 10 and day = 1
     group by year, mon, day
    )s;
```